# How can i install and launch calibre portable on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, installation, application-launch, calibre

I tried downloading and installing `calibre portable` in a new folder, in the "documents" library on Windows 7.

however the program doesn't launch (open) when i double click `calibre-portable.ext`. instead the arrow (mouse) shows the loading/processing symbol for about 7 seconds.

where did i go wrong?

## update

it worked well on a SD card. however i believe it would work quicker on the computer itself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what didn't work, specifically. Makes my answer meaningless though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [website](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_portable):

> To use, just run the portable installer and select the location 
>   where you would like the `Calibre Portable` folder.
>   To launch calibre, double click the `calibre-portable.exe` program inside the `Calibre Portable` folder.

The problem may be that you installed to the `Documents` folder, which has been said to cause problems.